# Message is not prompting for same store code when added twice in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure as below, where I am checking UNIQUE constraint that same `store_code` cannot be added twice. So once the user has inserted the `STORE_CODE` with name say `abc`. And again he is trying to insert the same store_code with same name. then he should get a prompt as `Record already exist`.

I have tried like below SP but it's not prompting the message.

```html
PROCEDURE INSERT_INTO_RRSOC_MST
  (    
    P_STORE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_STATE IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_CITY IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_Indication IN NUMBER,
    TBLDATA OUT NVARCHAR2
  ) 
  
  AS
  
  V_RRSOC_ID NUMBER:=0;
  
  BEGIN
    
    SELECT COUNT(RRSOC_ID) INTO V_RRSOC_ID FROM TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO 
    WHERE STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE AND isactive = 'Y';
    
    IF V_RRSOC_ID > 0 AND  P_Indication = 1 THEN
    
                              UPDATE TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO 
                              SET                                
                                  STATE = P_STATE,
                                  CITY = P_CITY,
                              WHERE STORE_CODE = P_STORE_CODE;   
  commit;  
  
    ELSE
    
     IF V_RRSOC_ID = 0 AND  P_Indication = 0 THEN
    
    INSERT INTO TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO      
                                   (
                                          STORE_CODE,
                                          STATE,     
                                          CITY                                      
                                          
                                   )
            
     VALUES
                                   (            
                                          P_STORE_CODE,
                                          P_STATE,
                                          P_CITY
                                            
                                   ) 
                                   
                                   RETURNING RRSOC_ID INTO TBLDATA;
commit;                                         
          TBLDATA:='Record Saved Succesfully';  
          
          ELSE
          
           TBLDATA:='Record already exist';  
    
          END IF;
  END IF;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        
  END INSERT_INTO_RRSOC_MST;
```

Comment: How are you calling this proc? What parameters you are passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of unclear what is `P_INDICATION` used for and which values it can get.

Code that follows distinguishes different `v_rrsoc_id` values and checks what's in `p_indication` to decide what to do.

Perhaps you shouldn't commit within a procedure, but let caller do that if everything is OK. Also, rolling back in `when others` will silently ignore errors and you won't know what went wrong. Maybe you should return error message in such a case.

```
PROCEDURE insert_into_rrsoc_mst (p_store_code  IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                 p_state       IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                 p_city        IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                 p_indication  IN     NUMBER,
                                 tbldata          OUT NVARCHAR2)
AS
   v_rrsoc_id  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (rrsoc_id)
     INTO v_rrsoc_id
     FROM tbl_rrsoc_store_info
    WHERE     store_code = p_store_code
          AND isactive = 'Y';

   IF v_rrsoc_id > 0
   THEN
      IF p_indication <> 1
      THEN
         tbldata := 'Record already exist';
      ELSIF p_indication = 1
      THEN
         UPDATE tbl_rrsoc_store_info
            SET state = p_state, city = p_city
          WHERE store_code = p_store_code;
      END IF;
   ELSIF v_rrsoc_id = 0
   THEN
      IF p_indication = 0
      THEN
         INSERT INTO tbl_rrsoc_store_info (store_code, state, city)
              VALUES (p_store_code, p_state, p_city)
           RETURNING rrsoc_id
                INTO tbldata;
      END IF;
   END IF;

   tbldata := 'Record Saved Succesfully';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      tbldata := 'Error: ' || SQLERRM;
END insert_into_rrsoc_mst;
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Now that we found out what `p_indication` means, procedure can be significantly simplified:

```
PROCEDURE insert_into_rrsoc_mst (p_store_code  IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                 p_state       IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                 p_city        IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                 p_indication  IN     NUMBER,
                                 tbldata          OUT NVARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
   IF p_indication = 1
   THEN
      UPDATE tbl_rrsoc_store_info
         SET state = p_state, city = p_city
       WHERE store_code = p_store_code;

      tbldata := 'Record updated';
   ELSIF p_indication = 0
   THEN
      INSERT INTO tbl_rrsoc_store_info (store_code, state, city)
           VALUES (p_store_code, p_state, p_city);

      tbldata := 'Record inserted';
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
   THEN
      tbldata := 'Record already exists';
END;
```

Comment: with duplicate store code, I am getting error as `Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (APP_PM.UNQ_STORE_CODE) violated` in place of this, I wanted to show message as 'Record already exist`

Comment: Could be. As the only *spot* in this piece of code that might raise the error is INSERT itself, once again - I suspect it is about P_INDICATION. What does it do? What do you pass to it? Why is P_INDICATION part of the SELECT COUNT(rrsoc_id) statement, if it affects uniqueness?

Comment: `P_Indication` can be either 1 or 0 depending upon the criteria . If its 1 then its `update` and if is 0 then its `INSERT`

Comment: Also, for updating I am getting message as `Record Saved Successfully`

Comment: Aha; OK. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: what is `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`

Comment: It is exception Oracle raises when unique index is being violated, and that's the one you want to *catch*.